# sourcing References in rmarkdown: workaround

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am working with markdonw v2, the `rmarkdown` package. Throughout the .Rmd file, I create links to websites or images

```
[Link1][pathLink1]
![Image1][pathImage1]
```

then, at the end of the document I give the references

```
[pathLink1]:http://website.com/linkes/Link1.md 
![pathImage1]:./images_rmd/
```

There are other reports that talk about the same citation and use same images in different contexts. I would like to create a separate file containing all the  links and path difinitions, so that I could simply source it at the end of each .Rmd file, like I would call in an R environment

```
source(/Rcode1.R)
```

**Question:** How do I "source" another file in .Rmd, so that the sourced code prints needed text strings into the .Rmd file?

This would offer some help with citations and scientific paper composition in HTML and PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/

````
```{r child, child = '~/path/to/child.Rmd'}
```
````

and similarly for .Rnw files:

```
<<child, child = '~/path/to/child.Rnw'>>=
@
```

And a full example: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/087-child-example.Rnw

Comment: gap in knowledge it is. Great, thanks, this works great. The only thing, i'm running into a problem referencing this child from the .Rmd located in the sibling of its parent. Is there an option to "go back a folder" in link specification of the child= "~/path.Rmd" specification?

Comment: if all of the childs (children?) are in the directory of the parent, you just need to `child = 'child1.Rmd'`; to move up a folder, you could `child = ../child1.Rmd'`