# Source nested R files within Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing a `Rmd` report with some `R` code chunks, *obviously*. My code structure is like the following:

- A `functions.R` script for custom functions
- `DataDependency.R` script for loading packages and my data, this already sources `functions.R` for exactly these tasks
- Some `analysis.R` scripts sourcing `DataDependency.R`
- Some more `furtheranalyis.R` sourcing `analysis.R`, since then I don't have to write some steps multiple times

Therefore, I am heavily depending on the function to source files in a *nested* way. However, I am unable to accomplish this in `RMarkdown` which gives me errors every single time (see below). Am I too stupid or is this functionality missing?! All tries so far resulted in error.

The other questions I saw regarding the topic only included sourcing of `.Rmd` within `.Rmd` files ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966109/how-to-source-r-markdown-file-like-sourcemyfile-r)) and the distinction between `source()` and `read_chunk()` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501622/making-knitr-run-a-r-script-do-i-use-read-chunk-or-source)). Both do not answer my question.

I already tried to make sure that it is really the *nested sourcing* that produces the errors. So here is a minimal working example:

#### MWE

File `mweA.R`

```
x = 1:10
```

and file `mweB.R`

```
source("./mweA.R")
y = x * x
```

Now, in my `.Rmd` file I want to just load file B (or both if I must) and then get on with it:

````
```{r}
source("./mweB.R")
plot(y ~ x)
```
````

And even if I do this:

````
```{r}
source("./mweA.R")
source("./mweB.R")
plot(y ~ x)
```
````

the same error occurs, namely:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection Calls: <Anonymous> ... source -> withVisible -> eval -> source -> file Execution halted
```

Please note that I don't get an error, if I just do `source("./mweA.R")` or source any other non-depending `R` script.

Hopefully, there is a (more or less) secret parameter that you have to specify in the chunk which solves all this. I really have a hard time with Rmarkdown's code chunks and it is often not clear to me, what the error is. This mainly keeps me from switching from `latex` to `RMarkdown`...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464318/sourcing-references-in-rmarkdown-workaround) might be helpful. Also, [another](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/07/09/making-use-of-external-r-code-in-knitr-and-r-markdown/) article on sourcing in `Rmarkdown`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice links, I was totally unaware of these options. However, no matter if I use the `child` option from the first or the `<<variableXY>>` option from the second example, I end up with errors. However, the first link directed to [this](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/) site, which I will now try to understand ;)

Comment: Ok, it seems to me that the `child` option is only useful to include other `.Rmd` or `.Rnw` files, right? And the function to *include* a `R` script is not my problem, but the sourcing of an `R` script within a `R` script is. It is no way obivous to me, why this should be a problem for Rmarkdown...


(Even though it will be very useful to me that I now know that you can include the code chunks within the `R` script via the `<< >>` marker!)

Comment: I never used `Rmarkdown`. I left these links as I did a quick search on your topic and they seemed like they might help you. From what I understand you need to google how to load other scripts in your `.Rmd` file, what are the differences etc

Comment: Thank you anyways. `Rmarkdown` is just so poorly documented and so I thought I should just ask for a quick answer to this *supposedly* simple problem. Of course I was searching through the net before ;)

Comment: Ok, I found a very annoying workaround: I have to comment out every line in my `R` scripts which does `source()`. Then I have to load all the scripts in their correct order. Also, since I have all paths defined from my R-Project point of view (and `RMarkdown` not) and all in one special `locations.R` script, I will have to change all paths to the `Rmarkdown` format. And then, finally, I cannot move up and down folders correctly... I guess `Rmarkdown` just does not fit my workflow/structure and is also **very frustrating!**

Comment: The error message you provided says that the file does not exist, indicating this is to do with the relative location of your files to one another, not an `rmd` issue. This is easily fixed with [`here`](https://github.com/krlmlr/here) which will resolve all your file paths regardless of whether they are called in an `rmd` directory or the project root.

Comment: If you run your own reprex there is no error. Are all the files located in the top directory of the project or are some in subdirectories?

Comment: Nice! The `here` package fixed my problem. I did realize that `R` and `RMarkdown` had a different root directory, but I forgot to adapt the `source` links within the `R` files to `RMarkdown`'s liking... With the `here` package that runs smoothly now. If you put your comment as an answer, I would accept it as such ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you're facing is not related to `knitr` or being able to correctly nest the documents but is instead a product of the R project ["working directory insanity"](https://gist.github.com/jennybc/362f52446fe1ebc4c49f) one faces as
`rmarkdown` will knit the document relative to the *file directory* as opposed to the *project root*. This leads to different relative paths depending on whether the document is run in the project session or `knitr` session.

In addition to the gist, [this issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/277) shows a number of workarounds:

**knitr specific**:

Set a root directory for all chunks to be evaluated relative to rather than the document location.

```
opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/Users/username/path_to_project')
```

**General case**:

Use either [`rprojroot`](https://github.com/krlmlr/rprojroot) or [`here`](https://github.com/krlmlr/here) (the latter is a wrapper over the former), which uses [several criteria](https://rprojroot.r-lib.org/articles/rprojroot.html) to determine the top level directory of your files. You need not be using an RStudio project for this to work.

Any reference to another local file is called using `here::here` which will resolve to the same location regardless of the subdirectory in which it's called.

```
source(here("functions.R"))
source(here("subdirectory", "DataDependency.R"))
source(here("subdirectory2", "furtheranalyis.R"))
```

This is probably a better solution as it doesn't rely on `knitr` options. Alternatively you can set the `root.dir` chunk using `rprojroot`:

```
opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())
```

provided you are using an RStudio project. If not, use `rprojroot::find_root` with a specified criterion.

Comment: Thanks! I was just going to answer myself. Actually, I tried the `here()` function and it worked *sometimes*. I don't know what happened, but somehow `.Rmd` only sometimes accepts the `here` function. I'm not sure, what changed between the tests, I would say nothing.
A more stable solution for me was the `find_rstudio_root_file()` function of the `rprojroot` package which I put in a small wrapper myself. To set a static path in `opts_knit$set(root.dir = "...") would be suboptimal imo. But I will try the above mentioned option.

Comment: This could be due to `here` relying on loading the package to setup its environment variables. I've revised the answer as `rprojroot` is perhaps more stable within a `knitr` setting.

Comment: Ok, now I got it! My problem with `here()` was totally unrelated to `knitr`. It is just that I also loaded the `lubridate` package which has a deprecated function of the same name. Of course, it couldn't work that way... So I take everything back about it being less stable for me!

Comment: For people potentially interested in this: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564564/r-2-functions-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-packages) I just put `here = here::here` at the top of my documents (which need sourcing)... this way it is shorter than always using `find_rstudio_root_file()` and it prevents conflicts with `lubridate`.

Comment: Small comment that might help someone, because I missed it for a while: if using the `opts_knit` solution, bear in mind the working directory change doesn't take effect until the _next_ chunk - sourcing still won't work if it's in the same chunk.